# Rails API - Versionist vs Rocket Pants

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest

Wondering if anyone has had any experiences with these gems?

- [Versionist](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/versionist)
- [RocketPants](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/rocket_pants)

Or can you recommend a better one to help me add a restful API to my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a few to checkout:

**Grape** - A bit like Sinatra but for building APIs. Built on top of Rack with minimal dependencies.

**Rocket Pants** - A set of tools for building APIs alongside Rails, inspired by Grape but with deeper Rails and ActionPack integration

**Rails::API** - Rails minus the stuff not needed for building apis.

I used Grape on a few projects, and I found it pretty good for small to medium APIs, especially if you want to add an API on top of an existing rails app, prefer a clean separation from your rails controllers and still be able to share model logic between the two.

It's like Sinatra which means defining endpoints is straight-forward and flexible, which can be a good or bad thing. On bigger APIs things can get a bit messy if you're not disciplined.

In comparison Rocket Pants is a little bit more opinionated, which gives you more structure and out of the box features. With Grape, as your API grows, you will need to find a way to refactor and structure the code yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bunch of information on this topic on RailsCast:

- [RABL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl)
- [The Rails API Gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem)
- [REST API Versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning)
- [Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)